# Is there a way to change the color of the selected radio button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a group of radio buttons, and a submit button. When I click on the submit button a message is shown telling me which radio button I clicked on. What I want to do now is change the color of the selected radio button, how can I do it? I have tried many things without success. Here is the code

```js
function selectedButton() {
  const optionContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".one");
  for (var i = 0; i < optionContainer.length; i++) {
    if (optionContainer[i].checked) {
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "You have selected: " + optionContainer[i].value;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="one" value="Male" />Male <br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="one" value="Female" />Female<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="one" value="Other" />Other<br>
<div id="display"> </div>
<button onclick="selectedButton()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Add class to your selected radio button. And that class should contain the style that you wanted.

Comment: Styling some control elements is tricky, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant see there comments below?

Comment: @RenatoManalili I can't see a single answer which would change _the color of the radio button_, which was asked ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the radio buttons to a `div` and then apply a CSS class when selected. Then, in your CSS, you can define the necessary styles.

```js
function selectedButton() {
  const optionContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".one");
  for (var i = 0; i < optionContainer.length; i++) {
    if (optionContainer[i].checked) {
      optionContainer[i].parentElement.classList.add('selected');
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "You have selected: " + optionContainer[i].value;
    } else {
      optionContainer[i].parentElement.classList.remove('selected');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  color: Red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" class="one" value="Male" />Male
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" class="one" value="Female" />Female
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" class="one" value="Other" />Other
</div>
<div id="display"> </div>
<button onclick="selectedButton()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Your solution is the simplest one. I hope the div that is wrapped around the input element doesn't have any side effect

Comment: Thank you, and to anyone who answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the whole input element in a span and using `parentNode` change the color of the full radio button

```js
function selectedButton() {
  const optionContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".one");
  for (var i = 0; i < optionContainer.length; i++) {
    if (optionContainer[i].checked) {
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "You have selected: " + optionContainer[i].value;
      optionContainer[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      optionContainer[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      optionContainer[i].parentNode.style.color = "yellow"
    } else {
      optionContainer[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
      optionContainer[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "";
      optionContainer[i].parentNode.style.color = ""
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<span><input type="radio" name="gender" class="one" value="Male" />Male</span> <br>
<span><input type="radio" name="gender" class="one" value="Female" />Female</span><br>
<span><input type="radio" name="gender" class="one" value="Other" />Other</span><br>
<div id="display"> </div>
<button onclick="selectedButton()">Submit</button>
```

You can enclose the labels in span and using `nextSibling` color them with the radio button

```js
function selectedButton() {
  const optionContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".one");
  for (var i = 0; i < optionContainer.length; i++) {
    if (optionContainer[i].checked) {
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "You have selected: " + optionContainer[i].value;
      optionContainer[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      optionContainer[i].nextSibling.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      optionContainer[i].nextSibling.style.color = "yellow"
    } else {
      optionContainer[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
      optionContainer[i].nextSibling.style.backgroundColor = "";
      optionContainer[i].nextSibling.style.color = ""
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="one" value="Male" /><span>Male</span> <br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="one" value="Female" /><span>Female</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" class="one" value="Other" /><span>Other</span><br>
<div id="display"> </div>
<button onclick="selectedButton()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function selectedButton() {
        const optionContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".one");
        for (var i = 0; i < optionContainer.length; i++) {
            if (optionContainer[i].checked) {
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "You have selected: " + optionContainer[i].value;
                optionContainer[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
            else {
                optionContainer[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can customize the style of radio button as your wish. Direct styling on radio will not work.

Below is an example.

You have not provided the style for `selected` class as well. Please add that to see the style change.

This is the style you needed.

```
.container.selected  input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```js
function selectedButton() {
  const optionContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".one");
  for (var i = 0; i < optionContainer.length; i++) {
    if (optionContainer[i].checked) {
      optionContainer[i].parentElement.classList.add("selected");
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "You have selected: " + optionContainer[i].value;
    } else {
      optionContainer[i].parentElement.classList.remove("selected");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* The container */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.container .checkmark:after {
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}

.container.selected  input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Radio Buttons</h1>
<label class="container"
  >One
  <input type="radio" class="one" checked="checked" name="radio" value="One" />
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container"
  >Two
  <input type="radio" class="one" name="radio" value="Two" />
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container"
  >Three
  <input type="radio" name="radio" class="one" value="Three" />
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container"
  >Four
  <input type="radio" class="one" name="radio" value="Four" />
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<div id="display"></div>
<button onclick="selectedButton()">Submit</button>
```